# Can tuple variadic template recursion be improved with C++14 index sequences?

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, variadic-templates, c++14

I have many variadic template functions to process `std::tuple` instances in my code similar to these ones:

```
// Convert JSON object to `std::tuple`

template<int TI = 0, typename... TS> 
std::enable_if_t<TI == sizeof...(TS)> toTpl(const JVal&, std::tuple<TS...>&) 
{ 
    // Do nothing (end of the recursion)
}

template<int TI = 0, typename... TS> 
std::enable_if_t<TI < sizeof...(TS)> toTpl(const JVal& mV, std::tuple<TS...>& mX)
{
    std::get<TI>(mX) = mV[TI].as<std::tuple_element_t<TI, decltype(mX)>;    
    toTpl<TI + 1, TS...>(mV, mX);
}
```

Basically, I use a template `int` counter and  `enable_if` to instantiate the template `0 -> sizeof...(TS)` times.

I was wondering if and how the new **C++14** `std::integer_sequence` or `std::index_sequence` could help in these situations.

I'm looking to make the code more readable (and easier to maintain). Improving compilation time is also a big plus.

I tried using `std::index_sequence` but ran into issues - I'm confused about its usage, especially when passing it as an argument in the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Option #1

```
template <typename... TS, std::size_t... Is> 
void toTpl(const JVal& mV, std::tuple<TS...>& mX, std::index_sequence<Is...>) 
{ 
    using Tuple = std::tuple<TS...>;
    mX = std::forward_as_tuple(mV[Is].as<std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>>()...);
}

template <typename... TS> 
void toTpl(const JVal& mV, std::tuple<TS...>& mX)
{
    toTpl(mV, mX, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(TS)>{});
}
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/effef8d1d1938f37)

---

#### Option #2

```
template <typename... TS, std::size_t... Is> 
void toTpl(const JVal& mV, std::tuple<TS...>& mX, std::index_sequence<Is...>) 
{ 
    using Tuple = std::tuple<TS...>;
    int dummy[] = { 0, ((void)(std::get<Is>(mX) = mV[Is].as<std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>>()), 0)... };
}

template <typename... TS> 
void toTpl(const JVal& mV, std::tuple<TS...>& mX)
{
    toTpl(mV, mX, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(TS)>{});
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10b9df83db6ec85d)

---

#### Option #3

```
template <std::size_t N, typename... TS>
void op(const JVal& mV, std::tuple<TS...>& mX)
{
    using Tuple = std::tuple<TS...>;
    std::get<N>(mX) = mV[N].as<std::tuple_element_t<N, Tuple>>();
}

template <typename... TS, std::size_t... Is>
void toTpl(const JVal& mV, std::tuple<TS...>& mX, std::index_sequence<Is...>) 
{ 
    int dummy[] = { 0, ((void)op<Is>(mV, mX), 0)... };
}

template <typename... TS> 
void toTpl(const JVal& mV, std::tuple<TS...>& mX)
{
    toTpl(mV, mX, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(TS)>{});
}
```

[**DEMO 3**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2de667051de00ab7)

Comment: `std::tuple_element_t<Is, std::tuple<TS...>>` is a complicating spelling of `TS` when `Is` is an index sequence.

Comment: It's not incorrect, it's unnecessarily verbose. `std::tuple_element_t<Is, std::tuple<Ts...>>...` is exactly equivalent to `Ts...`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd return the tuple by value to avoid unnecessary default construction and the nasty out parameter:

```
template <typename... Ts, std::size_t... Is> 
auto toTpl(const JVal& mV, std::index_sequence<Is...>) 
{ 
    return std::tuple<Ts...>{ mV[Is].as<Ts>()... };
}

template<typename... Ts> 
auto toTpl(const JVal& mV)
{
    return toTpl<Ts...>(mV, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{});
}

// Usage:

auto t = toTpl<int, double, long>(mV);
```

Maybe rename the function `as_tuple`:

```
auto t = as_tuple<int, char, std::string>(some_json_value);
```

which seems elegant and consistent with the usage of `JVal::as`. ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88d1b98fe47e057b))

Answer (score 2):

You may do something like:

```
template<typename Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
void toTpl(const JVal& mV, Tuple& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    std::initializer_list<int> {
        (std::get<Is>(t) = mV[Is].as<std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>>, void(), 0)...
    };
}

template<typename... TS>
void toTpl(const JVal& mV, std::tuple<TS...>& t)
{
    toTpl(mV, t, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(TS)>{});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
template <typename... T, std::size_t... I>
void toTpl_(const JVal& mV, std::tuple<T...>& mX, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    (void) std::initializer_list<int>{ (std::get<I>(mX) = mV[I].as<T>(), 0)... };
}

template <typename... TS>
void toTpl(const JVal& mV, std::tuple<TS...>& mX)
{
    toTpl_(mV, mX, std::index_sequence_for<TS...>() );
}
```

I don't think it gets much better than that. Returning a `tuple` and assigning that corresponds (after copy elision) to

```
template <typename... T, std::size_t... I>
void toTpl_(const JVal& mV, std::tuple<T...>& mX, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    mX = std::make_tuple( mV[I].as<T>()... );
}

template <typename... TS>
void toTpl(const JVal& mV, std::tuple<TS...>& mX)
{
    toTpl_(mV, mX, std::index_sequence_for<TS...>() );
}
```

Which obviously creates unnecessary copies.